# IDisposable and COM

Tags: .net, com, idisposable

Since COM objects hold non-memory resources but don't support IDisposable, I'm trying out some ideas to fake it. What do you think of my first attempt?

```
Public Function ComBlock(ByVal ParamArray comObjects As Object()) As IDisposable
    For i As Integer = 0 To comObjects.Length - 1
        If comObjects(i) Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("Null in parameter " & i)
        If Not Marshal.IsComObject(comObjects(i)) Then Throw New ArgumentException(comObjects(i).GetType.Name & " is not a COM object")
    Next

    Return New ComContext(comObjects)
End Function

Private Class ComContext : Implements IDisposable
    Private m_ComObjects As Object()
    Private m_Disposed As Boolean

    Sub New(ByVal comObjects As Object())
        m_ComObjects = comObjects
    End Sub

    Private Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        For Each item In m_ComObjects
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(item)
        Next

        GC.SuppressFinalize(Me)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the idea of where you're going.  I'm more inclined to wrap a COM object I'm using in an IDisposable type, where the type exposes the COM object's public members (think: Adapter).  The Dispose() method in your class will then handle the garbage collection of the COM object.

If you use a lot of COM objects, you could inherit from a base class to handle the disposal.  I haven't tested this code at all, but this is generally what I'm thinking...

```
public abstract class COMAdapter : IDisposable {

    protected abstract object COMObject { get; }

    public void Dispose() {
        Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(COMObject);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}

public class ConcreteAdapter : COMAdapter {
    private YourCOMType _comObject;

    protected override object COMObject {
         get { return _comObject; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would use generics instead of inheritance for the concrete types, but I see your point.